# PHP error in query with parameters missing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having an error here and your help would be much appreciated.

My code is below and this is the error I am getting:

PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/SANDBOX/PHP/.php on line 14

```
        <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","USER","PASSWORD","DATABASE");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        if($_POST[process]=="btn_add"){
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (user, password, type) VALUES ('".$_POST['user']."','".$_POST['password']."','".$_POST['type']."')" );
        }else if($_POST[process]=="btn_update"){
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET user='".$_POST['user']."',  password='".$_POST['password']."', type='".$_POST['type']."' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."' ;");
        }else if($_POST[process]=="btn_delete"){
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM  users WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."';");
        }while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($row)){
           echo $row['type'] ;
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
```

Comment: I tried all the suggestions below, the error is still appearing, i modified this line as it was an error on my part:

Comment: why you are using mysql_fetch_array when you are not fetching any record

Comment: It was written by a freelancer that once paid dropped the ball. I am stuck with troubleshooting everything and i am not a pro. Sorry. If i remove the entire line from while to the bracket it works and no more errors. But the operations take much LONGER to process than before.

Answer (score 3):

`mysqli_fetch_array($row)` to `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`

Comment: and what about **echo $row['type'] ;** ??

Answer (score 2):

```
always pass resource as an argument to mysql_fetch_array

}while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
           echo $row['type'] ;
        }
```

**But  i cant find 'select' in your code,you are using only 'update' and 'delete'.you dont need mysql_fetch_array.**

mysql_fetch_array Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

but you are not selecting anything from database so there is no need to use mysql_fetch_array.

[Read manual here](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array)

*Dont use mysql_ as they are depracated.*

Answer (score 0):

syntax error:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM  users WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."';");
```

change to:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM  users WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'");
```